# Initiate React components with data from Firebase database?

Tags: arrays, reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, components

I'm new to web development. In my site I have a message board when people can write to my **Firebase Realtime Database** (under '/message/'). The writing works fine, and I want to iterate all of the messages as an array of components "**Message**" that would be displayed inside the "**CmsMessages**" component, like this:

```
function CmsMessages () {
    return (
        <div>
            {[...Array(5)].map((_, i) => <Message key={i} />)} // say I have 5 messages
        </div>
    )
}
function Message () {
    return (
        <div>
            message title
        </div>
    )
}
```

This is how data is called from Firebase:

```
firebase.database().ref("message").on("value", function(snapshot) {
 let title = childSnapshot.val().title
})
```

But I could not figured out how to make this data to be returned from a functional component "Message, for each of my messages.

**Does anybody have an idea? Thanks!!!**

Edit: my wanted result is a separate component for any entry under "message", to be placed inside CmsMessages, like this:

```
CmsMessages
|
- Message (return: <div>{title of message #1}<div>)
|
- Message (return: <div>{title of message #2}<div>)
|
- Message (return: <div>{title of message #3}<div>)
|
- Message (return: <div>{title of message #4}<div>)
|
- Message (return: <div>{title of message #5}<div>)
```

Comment: Please replace the schematic representation of your databsae contents with the actual JSON (as text, no screenshots please). You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in the overflow menu (⠇) on your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to create a state hook for the title, and then call its setter when the data has loaded.

```
function Message () {
    const [title, setTitle] = useState("Loading...");

    firebase.database().ref("message").on("value", function(snapshot) {
      setTitle(childSnapshot.val().title);
    })
 
    return (
        <div>
            {title}
        </div>
    )
}
```

So here the app starts loading the title from the database when the `Message` component gets created, and then it updates the state when the title is available. This causes it to re-render the message with the title from the database.

Comment: Thanks @frank, but this is printing components only for the last database entry again and again... Instead of initiation a component for each message.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what the problem is in that case, and this definitely was missing from the code in your question. If your problem is on how to process multiple child nodes from your database, edit your question to show the JSON under `/message` (as text, no screenshots please). You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in the overflow menu (⠇) on your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: I wanted to initiate a new component for each entry under "message". In these components, I want the value of "title" from each entry: