# Mapping through realtime database using react

Tags: reactjs, database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, react-hooks

I am trying to map through each query a user enters and show them on the screen. For example I want to add a new task to firebase database (realtime database) and after that I want to map through each element in the database to show the cards in realtime, for example if I add a new task, update card structure instantly (not quite instantly ... but you get it).

This is how I tried to iterate through database,

```
const db = getDatabase();
const dbRef = query(
    ref(db, 'Homeworks/' + currentUser.uid),
    orderByChild('/priority')
);


return (

<div>
{onValue(
   dbRef,
   (snapshot) => {
      snapshot.forEach((childSnap) => {
          console.log(childSnap);
          // <h1>{childSnap.val()}</h1>
      });
   },
   {
      onlyOnce: true,
   }
 )}
</div>
)
```

But I get this error:

```
index.js:1 Warning: Functions are not valid as a React child. This may happen if you return a Component instead of <Component /> from render. Or maybe you meant to call this function rather than return it.
at div
at div
at Status (http://localhost:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:5412:83)
at Route (http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:142417:29)
at PrivateRoute (http://localhost:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:4486:14)
at Switch (http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:142619:29)
at AuthProvider (http://localhost:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:6355:3)
at Router (http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:142048:30)
at BrowserRouter (http://localhost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:141669:35)
at App
```

If I try to run the function outside the return statement and active listenting for changes I am able to get user homeworks.

```
    function displayUserData() {
    const db = getDatabase();
    const dbRef = query(
        ref(db, 'Homeworks/' + currentUser.uid),
        orderByChild('/priority')
    );

    onValue(
        dbRef,
        (snapshot) => {
            snapshot.forEach((childSnap) => {
                console.log(childSnap.val());
            });
        },
        {
            onlyOnce: true,
        }
    );
}

useEffect(() => {
    displayUserData();
});
```

**Console:**

```
{classRef: 'Mathematics', difficulty: 'Pice of cake', duration: 100, priority: 'Medium'}
{classRef: 'English', difficulty: 'Pice of cake', duration: 100, priority: 'Medium'}
```

I wonder if it is possible to render a div element in a return statmenet using a function or something.

[image: Firebase arhitecture]

This is an example of what I am talking about.

**Before:**
[image]

**After:**
[image]

**Thank you for your time :)**

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of your code, or other textual content. Instead post the actual text, and use the formatting tools of Stack Overflow to mark it up.

Comment: Also note that "I wasn't able to find a solution that work" is not an ideal problem description. What happens when you run this code? And what did you expect to happen? Is there any error message? If you step through this code line by line in a debugger, what is the first line that doesn't do what you expect it to do?

Comment: You can't call asynchronous code (such as `onValue`) in the render method/JSX. To render data that is loaded asynchronously, call `setState` with that data or use a `useState` hooks as for example shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64208033/initiate-react-components-with-data-from-firebase-database/64211296#64211296